# Creating a CRUD for a JSON object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, serialization

I'm new to javascript development and I have come across a problem that I assume has already been solved but I don't know how to find the answer.

Say I have a JSON object as follows:

```
// bagelList.json
{
    "description": "The bagel list. Who brings the bagels on what day.",
    "list": [
        {
            "date": "Nov 25",
            "name": "Cory"
        },
        {
            "date": "Nov 26",
            "name": "Jordan"
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to display the information in this object on a web page, but I want to display it prettily - as opposed to directly printing the JSON. I also want to allow users to update the list, add new entries, modify the description, etc.

I can display the data like so:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

    $.getJSON('bagelList.json', function(bagelData) {

        var items = [];
        $.each( bagelData.list, function( index, bagelAssignment ) {
            items.push( "<tr><td contenteditable="true">"
                        + bagelAssignment.date + "</td><td>"
                        + bagelAssignment.name + "</td></tr>" );
        });

        $("tbody#schedule").append( items.join( "" ) );

    });

});
```

However, all the data is now obfuscated a bit, by nature of being embedded in html. I could write a parser to go through all the table entries and recreate the original JSON object after the items have been updated by the user, but that seems like a kludge.

What is the right way to model the data such that it can be displayed in an appealing manner, but retain the ability to read and write from the object?

I assume this problem has already been solved many times before, so I don't want to go too far down the road of writing a CRUD only to find out that I just had to do XYZ and it just works.

Comment: The functionality you're describing is provided by frameworks such as [Backbone.js](http://backbonejs.org/), which are designed to facilitate two way binding of a view (your interface with the user) to a model (your JSON object).

Answer (score 2):

there are projects like jtable (http://www.jtable.org/Demo/Filtering , https://github.com/hikalkan/jtable)

But my thoughts on this - I think there are limited amount of cases where you'll need a table with pure CRUD operations; usually it will be something more fluid, more specific to your problem/domain.
I would go to [Angular](http://angularjs.org). Someone also mentioned backbone.js but I think in angular it will be seamless.

If you go down the angular path, I recommend [egghead](http://egghead.io/lessons), there are great videos there.

Comment: I kind of agree here. If you're looking for a framework that "just works" via magic, instead of having to wire up handlers to imperatively mutate the DOM in response to changes in the model, Angular is probably a much better choice than Backbone.